# Legacy SQL with datalab bigquery module

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

When querying an SQL module with a query written in Legacy sql, and then calling the execute() method, I get the error that we should use standard SQL.

Looking through the documentation, I see that the execute method has the argument dialect = legacy (http://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/datalab.bigquery.html), yet when using it, we get an error [see error in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dymtn.png)

Is there another problem? Is legacy SQL still supported by datalab bq module? is there a way to not have to move to standard SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Legacy SQL is no longer supported using the `google.datalab` namespace. Legacy SQL still works if you use the old `datalab` namespace but this option will be removed soon.

For the short term, can you try running `import datalab.bigquery as bq` instead of `import google.datalab.bigquery as bq`?

For the long term, the `google.datalab` namespace should be used with Standard SQL queries only.

Comment: Thanks! And where can I find the documentation for google.datalab

Comment: Click on the help icon in the Datalab web ui, then click the link titled "Datalab API"